# How to write xmla query to process tabular cube tables sequentially?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular, xmla

We have a tabular cube with quite a few tables in it and we have a sql job that runs multiple times a day to process the tables in the cube. Recently we added a couple of new tables and the sql job that runs continually fails because of an out of memory error. My understanding is that this is from sql server trying to run all the queries for all the tables at one time rather than sequentially (one after another). See the attached image [xmla tabular cube code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4oZs.png) for an example of how we've written our xmla for the cube processing job. How can this code be adjusted for sequential processing?

Comment: I guess there is no way to use tmsl and reprocess data sequentially according to this microsoft doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models-scripting-language-commands/sequence-command-tmsl
I will need to find a different way to process our cube now.

Comment: I think you can do this by including the `refresh` in a [`sequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models-scripting-language-commands/sequence-command-tmsl) with `"maxParallelism": 1`